# How to create a group page when creating a new group?

Tags: nodes, rules, organic-groups

When I create a new group (using the [Organic groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) module), I want to use the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module to create a new group referenced page.

I can create a new page using the *Create new entity* action, but I haven't been able to set the group reference/audience. I've tried using both *Add entity to Group* and *Set a data value*, but I can't figure out how to set the parameters.

```
{ "rules_create_1st_story_page" : {
"LABEL" : "Create 1st Story Page",
"PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
"OWNER" : "rules",
"REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "og" ],
"ON" : { "node_insert--story" : { "bundle" : "story" } },
"DO" : [
  { "entity_create" : {
      "USING" : {
        "type" : "node",
        "param_type" : "story_page",
        "param_title" : "Page 1 - Start here",
        "param_author" : [ "site:current-user" ]
      },
      "PROVIDE" : { "entity_created" : { "entity_created" : "Created entity" } }
    }
  },
  { "og_group_content_add" : { "entity" : [ "node" ], "group" : [ "node" ] } }
] }}
```

Comment: please include an export of the rule you have so far, so that a possible answer can explain how to correct it

Comment: @pierre-vriens, Hi Pierre I added the code. I know the og_group_content_add section is wrong, it's just the last spot that I tried to get the new entity it's group audience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the exported rule below, which is a variation of the (exported) rule in your question:

```
{ "rules_create_1st_group_page" : {
    "LABEL" : "Create 1st Group Page",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "ON" : [ "node_insert" ],
    "IF" : [
      { "node_is_of_type" : { "node" : [ "node" ], "type" : { "value" : { "group" : "group" } } } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "entity_create" : {
          "USING" : {
            "type" : "node",
            "param_type" : "post",
            "param_title" : "Page 1 - Start here",
            "param_author" : [ "site:current-user" ]
          },
          "PROVIDE" : { "entity_created" : { "grouppage_created" : "Created GroupPage" } }
        }
      },
      { "list_add" : { "list" : [ "grouppage-created:og-group-ref" ], "item" : [ "node" ] } },
      { "entity_save" : { "data" : [ "grouppage-created" ], "immediate" : 1 } }
    ]
  }
}
```

Some more details about "my" variation, about the content types involved:

- "`Group`" is the content type I'm using for my OG groups.
- "`Post`" is the content type which has an *Entity reference* field with machine name `og_group_ref` (and widget = OG reference), so that I can assign nodes of content type "Post" to the appropriate field. Be aware however, this field allows for unlimited values (not sure if that's your case also).

Some more details about the actual rule:

- Rules Event: After saving new content.
- Rules Condition: Content is of type `Group`.
- Rules Actions:

  - **`Create a new entity`**, of type `Post` (note the `grouppage_created` variable name I've used, instead of just the default `entity_created` ...).
  - **`Add an item to a list`**, whereas the list is `grouppage-created:og-group-ref` (a multi value field, remember, so you cannot/should not use "set a data value, a common mistake when creating custom rules ...), and the item to be added is ... you probably guessed it: the node (of type `Group`), that just got saved.
  - **`Save entity`**, for the `grouppage_created` (not sure if this Rules Action is really needed, but IMO it's a kind of safe (best?) practise to be sure that this newly created `grouppage_created`-entity also gets saved).

And yes I actually tested this rule in my own environment ... Sure enough, in my case a new node (of type `Post`) got created, after I created a new `Group`.

Your turn to adapt your rule (with your content types), to make it similar to my rule here (assuming you also allow *multiple values* for your `og-group-ref` field. If yours is single value, then probably all you need to change is to replace the Rules Action **`Add an item to a list`** by an action to **`Set a data value`** (using similar variables).

PS: I'm assuming your question is about D7.

Comment: @pierre-vriens Thank you Pierre.  I've tested your instructions and they work perfectly. The "add item to list" was the piece of the puzzle I missed, as you guessed I was using "set a data value" for a multi value og audience field.

Comment: @seanenroute merci for the feedback, and accept / +1!